# How to change an existing record?

Tags: reactjs

I do functionality to change the user. When I click on “change”, fields with user data appear, but I can’t change them, since I take the data from the database, how to make the old user data appear when I click on “change”, and they can be change?

[image]

[image]

```js
 const onGetUsersList = () => {
  return usersList.map(items => {
   return (
    <div key={items.id} className="users__card">
     <div className="card__data">
      <img src={items.imgUrl} alt="logo" width="100" />
      <h4>{`${items.firstName}`}</h4>
      <span className="user__details" onClick={() => onVisiblePopupDetails()}><FiList /></span>
      <span className="user__details" onClick={() => {
       setUserItem(items);
       onVisiblePopupUpdate();
      }}><FiEdit2 /></span>
      <span onClick={() => {
       onVisiblePopupWarning();
       setUserId(items.id)
      }}><FiTrash2 /></span>
     </div>
    </div>
   )
  })
 };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

And this is the code that opens a modal window in which you can change the user

```js
visiblePopupUpdate && 
   <div>
    <div className="modal__created-blur"></div>
    <div className="modal__created-modal">
     <div className="created__modal-header">
      <h2>Настройки пользователя</h2>
     </div>

     <div className="created__modal-body">
      <form className="body__form">
       <div className="modal__body-content-left">
        <div className="content__left-body-loader">
         <div className="load__field">
          <FiImage />
          <p>Загрузите аватар</p>
          <input 
           type="file" 
           className="input__file" 
           onChange={onHandleChangeFile}
          />
         </div>
         <div className="logo__prew">
          <img src={userItem.imgUrl} alt="logo" />
         </div>
        </div>

        <div className="content__left-body">
         <label>Ф.И.О.<span>*</span></label>
         <input 
          type="text" 
          className="input__text" 
          onChange={onHandleUserName}
          id="name"
          value={userItem.firstName}
         />
        </div>
       </div>
       

       <div className="modal__body-content-right">
        <div className="content__right-body">
         <label>Должность</label>
         <input 
          type="text" 
          className="input__text"
          onChange={onHandleUserPosition} 
         />
         </div>

        <div className="content__right-body">
         <label>Дата</label>
         <input 
          type="text" 
          className="input__text" 
          id="location"
         />
        </div>
       </div>
      </form>
     </div>

     <div className="created__modal-bottom">
      <button type="button" className="close__button" onClick={() => {
       onVisiblePopupUpdate();
      }}>Закрыть</button>

      <button type="button" 
       className="success__button" 
       onClick={() => {
        updateUser(userItem.id, userItem.imgUrl)
       }}>Сохранить
      </button>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

And all that needs to be done is to get old data that can be changed ...

Comment: When you click on button you have to pass data for the particular item to the popup component so that passed or old data visible

Comment: They are visible, only I can not do anything with them, the old username is displayed in input, and I cannot delete it and enter a new username, because input cannot be changed

Comment: Ohh then it is sure the problem of css like something over popup which hides user interaction. Please try to inspect in dev tool in browser.